# Mysql restore from backup file

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-backups, database-restore

I made a backup from a database in mysql with the command `mysqldump -u root -p Test > test.sql` and it saved correctly the database in the file, but when I restore it in a different database with the command `mysql -u root -p Test2 < test.sql` after create the new and clean `Test2` database, it restore the originally backed up `Test` database and not the one that I want, if someone could tell me how can I change this behavior or what am I doing wrong, I'll appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: is a `CREATE DATABASE` || `USE DATABASE` line in your `test.sql` file?

Comment: just noticed you're using the `mysql` command to import - use `mysqldump`

Comment: Yes it is and if I change it manually it'll do what I want, but I would like to find a way to do it without edit the file manually

Comment: Hm.. not sure tbh mysqldump, in my experience doesn't export a CREATE DATABASE line...

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this code.

Step 1:

```
mysql -u <user> -p < db_backup.dump
```

Step 2

```
USE <database-name-here>;
```

I hope it will help you